# Getting a weird warning in console while using django 3.1 in windows 10 local machine

Tags: python, django, windows, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 3.1 on my window 10 machine. I am also using the virtual environment. While running starting the server it does not show any error or warning but while navigating it sometimes show this weird warning or we can say error. So what can be the reason of this error?

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 8931)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python 3.8.2\Lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\python 3.8.2\Lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\python 3.8.2\Lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\NAMANT~1\Desktop\MIRROS~1\MIRROR~2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\NAMANT~1\Desktop\MIRROS~1\MIRROR~2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "c:\python 3.8.2\Lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: I get this error whenever I run my test environment and jump into the admin backend tables.  It has never affected anything though, so I gave up trying to resolve it, after googling it for an hour or two.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using both chrome and firefox and it is happening in both cases. It doesn't affect the running server but sometimes it take much time to load page.